# Does wordpress templates always in files or in database?

Tags: php, themes, templates, page-template, headers

I have theme and in header.php and I found this templates (see attached screenshot).
But there is no content directory in template directory. Even I searched for those files (header-private.php and header-public.php) but can't found. Then how those templates loading?
[image]

Comment: Hopefully I have correctly understood your question, and just a friendly reminder - please add the actual code into your post and not just a screenshot of the code - because when it's an image, it'll be cumbersome for us to type out the code.. ✌

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But there is no content directory in template directory.

Actually, with the following:

- `get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'header-private' );`
- `get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'header-public' );`

WordPress will search *in the `templates` folder* for `content-header-private.php` or `content-header-public.php`, and if found, it is loaded. Else, WordPress will attempt to load the `content.php` file instead.

So WordPress (or `get_template_part()`) will not search in a folder named `content`, and instead, the "content" part in `templates/content` means, "*search for PHP files where the name **begins with `content-`** in the `templates` folder, and if none found, please load `content.php` if it exists*".

Other examples that might help:

```php
// loads content.php
get_template_part( 'content' );

// loads templates/content.php
get_template_part( 'templates/content' );

// loads templates/content-foo-bar.php OR templates/content.php
get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'foo-bar' );

// loads templates/content/foo-bar.php OR templates/content/foo.php
// i.e. the function will now search in the "content" (sub-)folder
get_template_part( 'templates/content/foo', 'bar' );
```

Check out the [`get_template_part()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) for more details about (using) the function.

> Even I searched for those files (header-private.php and
> header-public.php) but can't found.

If the `templates` folder does not have these files: `content-header-private.php`, `content-header-public.php` and `content.php`, then they might be in the *parent theme* if you are using a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/), so try searching in the parent theme's `templates` folder.

And it's because `get_template_part()` will first search in the child and then parent theme, so the template that's loaded could be the one in the parent theme.

Technically though, it's actually `locate_template()` which searches and loads the template, so you might also want to check the function's [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/).

Comment: Also, if they're using a child theme these files could be in the parent theme.